# WordPress + Contact Form 7: No se envían formularios, pero SMTP de prueba se envía y acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras está habilitada

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Edito @Dianne: La solución fue cambiar el plugin de SMTP que usaba al SMTP de Postman. Gracias a @A.Cedano por la respuesta :) Con eso y un texto de formulario normal se arregló el problema.

Tengo un problemilla con una página que estoy desarrollando en mi localhost de WordPress (el tema que uso es el Rosa, esta es su dirección: [Tema](https://themeforest.net/item/rosa-an-exquisite-restaurant-wordpress-theme/7920093)) y es que no se envía el formulario (estoy usando contact form 7). Como ya me pasó alguna vez algo parecido, lo primero que hice fue asegurarme de que el formulario estaba correctamente escrito. Todo estaba bien y por si acaso era algo de ahí, para descartarlo copié y pegué de otra página que hice con el mismo plugin, el formulario y la cabecera y cuerpo del mensaje. Me he asegurado de que todos los campos están bien escritos, realizando la comparación (pero con los datos de mi e-mail).

Una vez me aseguré de que estaba todo bien, como seguía sin funcionar, instalé el plugin: WP Email SMTP  y configuré el mismo para permitir el SMTP. Hice la prueba del test y recibí, en mi e-mail de Gmail, el correo de prueba sin ningún problema (por lo que se descarta que esté mal hecha la configuración SMTP).

Finalmente, recordé un problema que tuve hace unos meses con las cuentas de Gmail y que me daba el mismo fallo (lo pregunté aquí) así que fui a la sección de seguridad de las cuentas de Google y me he asegurado tener activado en la zona de seguridad el acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras.

Todo lo anterior está correctamente realizado, pero cada vez que intento rellenar los datos del formulario y enviar el mismo (con todos y cada uno de los campos debidamente completados) me salta el error. He probado a rellenar el formulario tras hacer control+f5 por si era problema de caché y lo mismo con un navegador de incógnito, pero sigue saliendo el mismo error.

He mirado en internet pero no he encontrado soluciones (todas hacían referencia al SMTP y alguna a la seguridad de cuentas de google, y esos pasos ya los había hecho) y en este mismo foro. Lo mas parecido que he encontrado ha sido una pregunta de un error similar en Laravel, pero no me ha aclarado nada (aunque tampoco estaban usando lo que estoy utilizando).

¿Alguno sabe porque sigue saliéndome el error? Os dejo una imagen del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Con el WP_DEBUG activado, miré la consola de Google Chrome para ver que errores podían estar saliendo. Estos son los que me ha dicho (aunque dos son del mapa de Google porque aún no lo tengo configurado, pero eso no debiera de afectar al formulario puesto que van separados).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la línea 465 hay lo siguiente (marca un warning en createShadowRoot() ) :

```
shadow = document.documentElement.createShadowRoot();
```

Y el contexto de esa línea de código es el siguiente:

```
var propertyFilters = new CSSPropertyFilters(window, getPropertyFilters,
                                           addElemHideSelectors);

  // Use Shadow DOM if available to don't mess with web pages that rely on
  // the order of their own <style> tags (#309).
  //
  // However, creating a shadow root breaks running CSS transitions. So we
  // have to create the shadow root before transistions might start (#452).
  //
  // Also, using shadow DOM causes issues on some Google websites,
  // including Google Docs, Gmail and Blogger (#1770, #2602, #2687).
  if ("createShadowRoot" in document.documentElement &&
  !/\.(?:google|blogger)\.com$/.test(document.domain))
  {
shadow = document.documentElement.createShadowRoot();
shadow.appendChild(document.createElement("shadow"));

// Stop the website from messing with our shadowRoot
if ("shadowRoot" in Element.prototype)
{
  runInDocument(document, function()
  {
    var ourShadowRoot = document.documentElement.shadowRoot;
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "shadowRoot");
    var shadowRoot = Function.prototype.call.bind(desc.get);

    Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "shadowRoot", {
      configurable: true, enumerable: true, get: function()
      {
        var shadow = shadowRoot(this);
        return shadow == ourShadowRoot ? null : shadow;
      }
    });
  }, null);
}
  }
```

Si hago click en enlace al que me lleva el warning, me lleva al siguiente enlace:  [Chromestatus](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448). Doy por hecho que todos podréis verlo. Sin embargo, por mas que leo lo que sale en esa página, no logro entenderlo bien (mi inglés no es muy bueno precisamente).

Comment: Entonces, en resumen: los mensajes se envían, pero te sale el mensaje _hubo un error intentando enviar su mensaje..._ ¿He entendido bien?

Comment: Si, entendiste bien el problema. Pero ese error sale con una configuración SMTP correcta, la seguridad de google bien configurada para evitar que lo bloquee y habiendo copiado la estructura de otro formulario que hice en la que nunca hubo ningún problema con los formularios (desde mayo del 2016 hasta ahora).

Comment: Activa el modo DEBUG de tu instalación con esta línea en tu archivo `wp-config.php`: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` y edita tu pregunta con los resultados al usar tu formulario. Recuerda editar lo que corresponda.

Comment: Si has comprado la plantilla, el autor de la misma te dará soporte. Tengo cuenta allí desde hace años y funciona muy bien.

Comment: @toledano , ya puse lo que vi con el WP_DEBUG true, a través de lo que he visto mediante la consola del Chrome. No he visto ninguna diferencia entre tener el debug activado o no, quizás lo haya utilizado mal, pero adjunté todo lo que vi.

Comment: @MarcLemien si pudiera, les escribiría. El problema principal es que a mi me enviaron por correo los archivos de la plantilla y un código que validó la plantilla, pero no tengo ningún tipo de acceso a la web de ellos y creo que no se puede preguntar si no has comprado como tal (que es mi caso, quienes compraron esa plantilla fueron otros, no yo).

Comment: Dianne, mis respetos para detallar tanto en la pregunta, así da gusto leerla y darte una ayuda con ganas :D

Comment: Estoy contigo @fredyfx es flipante!!!...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Solución del problema para este caso:**
>
> En este caso, el problema se ha resuelto implementando parte de lo que
>   sugería el creador del plugin en la parte  (B) de esta respuesta:
>
> **En algunos casos, es posible resolver este problema utilizando otro servidor de correo**. [Postman SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/) es uno de los plugins que le
>   ayudarán a hacer eso.
>
> La solución ha sido pues utilizar el plugin Postman SMTP.

---

#### A. POSIBLE BUG A PARTIR DE WP 4.4.1

Tu problema ha sido reportado por varios usuarios, a partir de Wordpress 4.4.1, según afirma el [creador del plugin](https://contactform7.com/2016/01/15/red-border-error-issue-on-wordpress-441/):

Aquí te dejo la traducción:

---

> Problema de error en WordPress 4.4.1 JANUARY 15, 2016 TAKAYUKI MIYOSHI
>
> Actualmente estamos viendo reportes de problemas en un patrón
>   específico en el foro de soporte. El problema más común es:
>
> Después de enviar un formulario, verá "No se pudo enviar el mensaje"
>   con un borde rojo. El correo no se envía. Afirman que el problema
>   comenzó después de actualizar a WordPress 4.4.1.
>
> No se han encontrado bugs hasta ahora relacionados con este problema,
>   en WordPress o el plugin Contact Form 7.
>
> Después de examinar muchos informes, **descubrí que algunos de ellos
>   tenían configuraciones erróneas en su configuración de correo y podían
>   resolver el problema corrigiendo la configuración. Es posible que la
>   configuración errónea en la configuración de correo sea la principal
>   causa de este problema en muchos casos.**
>
> Una gran parte de la configuración errónea se ve en el campo `De` en su
>   encabezado de correo. El campo `De` no es una etiqueta o decoración;
>    debe ser una dirección de correo electrónico válida que tenga  la sintaxis correcta. De lo contrario, los servidores de correo no podrán
>   entregar el correo.
>
> Siguiendo la especificación estándar, un valor de campo `De` debe ser
>   una dirección de correo electrónico: `john@example.com`. También puede ser un nombre y una dirección de correo
>   electrónico rodeados de "`<`" y "`>`": `John Smith <john@example.com>` **Aunque puede utilizar las [etiquetas de  correo](https://contactform7.com/tag-syntax/) de Contact Form 7 en el valor de campo, le recomiendo que no
>   utilice etiquetas de correo a menos que entienda completamente cómo
>   funcionan. Usar una dirección de correo electrónico es seguro**.
>
> ¿Qué dirección de correo electrónico debe utilizar en el campo `De`?
>   **Debe utilizar una dirección perteneciente al mismo dominio que el sitio. La [mejor práctica](http://contactform7.com/best-practice-to-set-up-mail/) es usar wordpress @ {your-site-domain} y
>   preparar la dirección en su host.**
>
> Usted puede estar preguntándose por qué había sido capaz de enviar
>   correo incluso con la configuración de correo no válido. ¿Por qué este
>   problema de repente empezó con WordPress 4.4.1? No estamos seguros,
>   pero lo importante es que los campos de encabezado de correo deben
>   tener valores válidos independientemente de las versiones de
>   WordPress. Este es un buen momento para revisar su configuración de
>   correo.

---

#### B. OTRAS VÍAS DE SOLUCIÓN PLANTEADAS EN EL FAQ

El [FAQ de Contact Form 7](https://contactform7.com/faq/i-get-an-error-message-with-a-red-border-so-how-can-i-solve-this/) da también estas posibilidades de solución al problema. Aquí la traducción:

**Recibo un mensaje de error con un borde rojo. Entonces, ¿cómo puedo solucionar esto?**

El borde rojo significa que el formulario intentó enviar correo con `wp_mail ()`, pero falló. Para resolver el problema, es necesario en primer lugar averiguar la razón real por la que está fallando.

Podría haber varias razones tales como que **la configuración de correo no era válida**.

Véase también: Problema de error del borde rojo en WordPress 4.4.1 (ya traducido más arriba).

**El envío también fallaría si el servidor de correo estaba inactivo**, o debido a otros problemas. En este caso, será más difícil resolver el problema por usted mismo. Le sugeriría que contacte a su compañía de hosting para obtener ayuda. Pueden comprobar los **registros de errores** para averiguar el motivo del fallo.

**En algunos casos, es posible resolver este problema utilizando otro servidor de correo**. [Postman SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/) es uno de los plugins que le ayudarán a hacer eso.

### ACTUALIZACIÓN C

#### C. Error en el Wordpress Core

Cambiar los valores en la línea 352 del archivo:

`wp-includes/pluggable.php`

Cambiar:

```
$phpmailer->setFrom( $from_email, $from_name );
```

por

```
$phpmailer->setFrom( $from_email, $from_name, false );
```

Fuente: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/236421

Comment: Buenas :)

Pero el servidor SMTP ya lo tengo configurado, aunque es otro plugin (no es el postman) y funciona, porque me llega a mi e-mail uno de prueba (como se ve en las imágenes que puse). He probado a poner el mismo e-mail en el campo "De" que tengo en el campo "Para" y sigue sin funcionar. Además, tal y como dije, he copiado y pegado otro formulario que en su día funcionaba perfectamente con esta configuración... Acerca de la configuración del correo, uso el de Gmail y con otros formularios nunca tuve problemas, pero verifiqué (sigo en otro comentario)

Comment: que la configuración para recibir e-mails de destinatarios poco seguros esté habilitada (es decir, que se puedan recibir esos e-mails y no sean bloqueados de forma automática). ¿Sería mejor que cambiase el plugin del servidor SMTP al de postman, a ver si así se envía el formulario?

Comment: @Dianne Ellos recomiendan usar el plugin PostMan, al parecer funciona mejor. Puedes probar con él. Pero... no sé si has leído esto: https://contactform7.com/best-practice-to-set-up-mail/ dice entre otras cosas: _Also, be careful not to make the message body empty or too short. It not only makes the mail look like spam, it makes mail sending function fail on some hosts._ Incluso por un mensaje corto te puede fallar, pues puede ser considerado spam. ¿Has probado **tratando de enviar un mensaje normal, con texto entendible** y no solamente rrrrr?

Comment: @Dianne prueba también lo planteado a la **actualización C**.

Comment: gracias. Desconozco el motivo por el cual no funcionaba el plugin SMTP que había elegido (es extraño porque en otros formularios me ha funcionado siempre y no ha habido nunca ningún problema con el), pero al utilizar el Postman he logrado enviarme el formulario de prueba, para poder verificar que funciona. Mil gracias de verdad. Ahora queda solo entender porque no funcionaba bien el otro... pero bueno, eso es lo menos importante ahora. 

¿Podrías editar tu respuesta para señalar que ha sido el cambio de plugin de SMTP? Por si a alguien le pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Había probado otros plugins de SMTP (unos 2 o 3 mas) por si acaso era el plugin y no me funcionó con ellos, así que los eliminé (no recuerdo cuales eran) y descarté que fuese el SMTP. Encuentro curioso esto. Mil gracias igualmente @A.Cedano :)

Comment: @Dianne Ok. Editaré la respuesta. Me alegro de que te haya funcionado. A mi me pasaba lo mismo que te ha pasado. Los plugins de formularios de contacto funcionaban durante un tiempo y luego debido a actualizaciones de Wordpress dejaban de funcionar, además algunos de ellos invadían mi base de datos y eso no me gustaba así que opté por otra alternativa que me funciona muy bien: Formularios de Google (https://www.google.es/intl/es/forms/about/) son muy fáciles de crear, recibes las respuestas en una hoja de cálculo, hay un complemento que informa por email cuando alguien deja un comentario.